# Sorting a table with a column with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sorting, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this :

[image]

How can I sort it out in the form below :

[image]

Each set of records has been marked by **a** FlagID at end

Comment: Is there a reason why you're only marking the last record of the set with the `FlagID` (rather than all the set's records)?

Comment: surely, If I marking all set of record with FlagID and use Order by FlagId, Row. thanks

Comment: Yes, if all `FlagID` values are properly populated, you could use `ORDER BY FlagID, Row`. This would be the recommended approach.

Answer (score 2):

> Each set of records has been marked by a FlagID at end

I assume this means that each record is implicitly associated with the first non-null `FlagID` value that occurs at or after its position along the `ID` primary key. Thus, we can use a correlated subquery to project this implicit `FlagID` value for each record, sort by it, then sort by your `Row` column as tiebreaker for each set.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable T1
ORDER BY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 T2.FlagID
    FROM YourTable T2
    WHERE T2.ID <= T1.ID
      AND T2.FlagID IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY T2.ID DESC
),
    T1.Row
```

However, if you're able to alter the database content, I would recommend you to explicitly populate all the `FlagID` fields, as this would make your life easier. If you do so, then the query becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable T1
ORDER BY T1.FlagID,
         T1.Row
```